# Capacity of groups in Linux

Tags: permissions, nfs, groups

How many users can be added to particular group in Linux (Ubuntu/Red Hat)? In NFS network set up in Lab, file/ownership permissions everything got messed up when the user number increased beyond certain number and group members were not able to access respective files. Can we extend this limit? What should be done to increase this group capacity?

Comment: Is the problem with a group having N members or a user being a member of N groups?

Comment: The problem is with a group having N members. No user of this group is able to access file which is owned by same group. But instead of showing group name, it is showing GID.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of groups as user can be part of on a Linux system is indeed [limited](http://www.j3e.de/ngroups.html). But this is a tuneable setting; look for `NGROUPS_MAX` in `limits.h`. Linux Kernel 2.6.3+ has this set at 65536.

```
/usr/include/linux$ grep NGROUP limits.h
#define NGROUPS_MAX    65536    /* supplemental group IDs are available */
```

But there is another limit for NFS(v4) and this is a lot lower: [16](http://www.xkyle.com/solving-the-nfs-16-group-limit-problem/) and this is a limitation of `auth_sys` not of NFS.

> Can we extend this limit?

From the link:

> The Best Solution Ever!: A New Option for the NFS Server
>
> I hope this is the first thing you read after encountering this
>   problem for the first time. I hope that you don’t have to read any of
>   the other “solutions” on this page. I hope you haven’t wasted your
>   time doing other work-arounds. I hope you are in an environment where
>   you are able to use this solution:
>
> ```
> rpc.mountd --manage-gids
> ```
>
> rpc.mountd is the program that actually serves nfs. The –manage-gids
>   option allows the server to just plain ignore the incoming bogus 16
>   groups from the client, and allow the nfs server to look it up for
>   itself. Straight from the man page:
>
> ```
>    -g  or  --manage-gids
>           Accept requests from the kernel to  map  user  id  numbers  into
>           lists  of  group  id  numbers for use in access control.  An NFS
>           request will normally (except when using Kerberos or other cryp-
>           tographic  authentication)  contains  a  user-id  and  a list of
>           group-ids.  Due to a limitation in the NFS protocol, at most  16
>           groups ids can be listed.  If you use the -g flag, then the list
>           of group ids received from the client will be replaced by a list
>           of  group ids determined by an appropriate lookup on the server.
> ```
>
> You must have a modern (past 2007) version ( >1.0.12 ) of the linux
>   nfs server for this option and a recent kernel (>2.6.21) to go with
>   it. Most modern distros can do it, but if you are using Solaris or
>   some sort of embedded NFS appliance, you are probably out of luck.
>
> On a modern Ubuntu server it has this option on by default. Check with
>   the documentation on your distro on how to turn it on properly. Then
>   party. I can stop writing this blog post because everyone runs modern
>   versions of Linux for their NFS servers right??? :)

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind, I use Ubuntu 12.04LTS with kernel 3.2.0-75-generic. The answer you provided is related with "Number of Groups", my problem is with "Number of users per group". Anyway I deleted some users from the same group and it seems that it working properly now. In my case this number seems to be around 130. No idea how it came from or how to change this.